# How can I cast only my android screen to my tv

Tags: stock-android, chromecast

I have a Chromecast and I want to cast my android screen to my tv (mainly youtube) but not the audio, I looked online to find any answers and I found that I have to double broadcast I did it once (I assume) and could not replicate it I also cant google a guide to doing this because I just find other things that I am not looking for. So, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure both devices are on same network, open Youtube app on the android device and choose cat option (icon) it will detect nearby devices and select your TV

Comment: But thats just normal casting... It will cast both sound and sound

Comment: Video and sound***